# Recording function names with Log4Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to log MethodName when wrapping Log4net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157232/how-to-log-methodname-when-wrapping-log4net)

I have tons of requests in log4net that show up manually as ": activity". The requests are all manually built and somewhat clumsy. Is there any way for Log4Net to pick up the source function and record that automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, 
you can use pattern layout, by specifying the %method flag you will output the calling method name, see the docs here:

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html

e.g.

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%d %-5p %C %method %m%n " />
      </layout>
```

but pay attention this can slow down the performance if you log a lot of messages ore your application is time-critical.