# How to log Class name, Method Name and a line number ,when wrapping Log4net?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, logging, log4net

**What is my purpose:** log file output will contain the name of the class, method and the line that was wrote by the log (in the example below – Program, Main, 16)

**The problem:** the log file output is contain the name of the class, method and the  line of the wrapper class and not the details of the "main" function.

I have 2 projects

**Project 1 "Log4netCommon"** - that include the log4net.dll and wrapper for the log functionally

**Project 2 "NoDependenceLog4net"**- that reference to "Log4netCommon" and contain the main function that

Part of My config file:

```
<appender name="File" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <file value="C:/Users/zxc/Desktop/MyFile.txt" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" >
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %c - %m%n  %logger [%-5method] %line - [%file] [%location]" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Project 2 "NoDependenceLog4net

```
namespace NoDependenceLog4net
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logManager = new Log4netCommon.LogManager();
            var log = logManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

            log.Info("we are logging without reference of log4net");
            log.Warn("Warn");
            log.Error("Error");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Project 1 "Log4netCommon

```
namespace Log4netCommon
{
    class LoggerAdapter : Log4netCommon.ILogger
    {
        private readonly ILog _log;

        internal LoggerAdapter(ILog log)
        {
            _log = log;
        }

        public void Debug(object message)
        {
            _log.Debug(message);
        }
        public void Info(object message)
        {
            _log.Info(message);
        }


    namespace Log4netCommon
    {
        public class LogManager : ILogManager
        {
             static LogManager()
            {
                log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo("C:\\Users\\zxc\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Log4netCommon\\Log4netCommon\\AppPatternLayout.config"));
            }

            public ILogger GetLogger(Type type)
            {
                var logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(type);
                return new LoggerAdapter(logger);
            }
        }

}
```

namespace Log4netCommon
{
    public interface ILogManager
    {
        ILogger GetLogger(Type type);
    }
}

"Similar" issues that I was looked

[When using wrapper, how to preserve class and method name for Log4Net to log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049992/when-using-wrapper-how-to-preserve-class-and-method-name-for-log4net-to-log)

[wrong file and line in log4net wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852508/wrong-file-and-line-in-log4net-wrapper)

[How to log MethodName when wrapping Log4net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157232/how-to-log-methodname-when-wrapping-log4net)

Comment: Have you also seen this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149844/how-to-log-method-name-when-using-wrapper-class-with-log4net

Comment: Yes,  i saw it.  But i didn't know how to combine it with my code.

Comment: In your log methods in the `LoggerAdapter` you have to change your methods to use the following scheme: `public void Debug(object message)
        {
            _log.Logger.Log(typeof(LoggerAdapter), LogLevel.Debug, message, null);` etc
        }`

Comment: Thanks @nemesv it was very helpful. I will check it more deeply and will update you.