# How to log methodName when Log4net is wrapped in a convenience class

Tags: c#, logging, elasticsearch, log4net

I have a C# WebApi application which stores log messages into ElasticSearch. I'm using the log4net library

This is one log record:

```
{
      "_index" : "log-2016.06.23",
      "_type" : "logEvent",
      "_id" : "AVV9rAqpZnaTkXOWfRfY",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "timeStamp" : "2016-06-23T14:31:14.0610345Z",
        "fileName" : "C:\\Users\\gianluca.ghettini\\Desktop\\EOS\\Eurotherm.Data\\Uhh\\UhhFileImporter.cs",
        "lineNumber" : "1063",
        "fullInfo" : "Eurotherm.Data.Uhh.UhhFileImporter.LogMessage(C:\\Users\\gianluca.ghettini\\Desktop\\EOS\\Eurotherm.Data\\Uhh\\UhhFileImporter.cs:1063)",
        "methodName" : "LogMessage",
        "threadName" : "7",
        "hostName" : "GBWOTIOM68052D"
      }
```

The `methodName` is always "`LogMessage`" instead of being the actual method that made the log line. That's because I wrapped the log4net library inside a convenience class.

Is there a way to tell log4net to use the caller method as the "methodName"?

Comment: No, that's an unavoidable consequence of a "convenience class". You would need to determine the method name yourself.

Comment: @stuartd how very inconvenient...

Comment: @stuartd I'm using the answer you provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957276/method-name-in-log4net-c-sharp

Comment: @stuartd but the one provided by jgauffin looks way better  (same post)

Comment: I would concur, wrapping log4net in another class removes a lot of the flexibility that gives log4net it's power